# Can't Start Wireless After Performing "airmon-ng check kill" on terminal

Tags: networking, wireless, 17.04

I'm using Ubuntu 17.04 dual boot with windows 10.

Last day I tried to learn about using it to get connected to an wireless connection, and as the tutorial asked me to do `airmon-ng check kill` or `airmon-ng stop wlan0` or something like that, it seem to be normal and my wireless connection turned off, but after that I was asked again to start the `wlan0`, but can't. And my wireless connection won't turn on until I restart my laptop.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

To restart your internet connection after running `sudo airmon-ng check kill` and/or `sudo airmon-ng stop wlan0`, first get the Wi-Fi chip out of monitor mode, and then start the network service:

```
sudo airmon-ng stop wlan0mon
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
```

Answer (score 1):

`sudo airmon-ng stop wlo1mon`

my interface name is wlo1
check your interface name by command
`iwconfig`

if your interface  name is wlan
then command is 
`sudo airmon-ng stop wlanmon`

Answer (score 0):

Please check to see if running air*mon*-ng, your wireless card has switched to Monitor mode:

```
iwconfig
```

If so, change it to Managed mode:

```
sudo ifconfig wlan0 down
sudo iwconfig wlan0 mode managed
sudo ifconfig wlan0 up
```

Any improvement?

Answer (score 0):

In case the wireless board is identified by **wlan0mon** type:

```
airmon-ng stop wlan0mon
```

that should do it.

Comment: Hi Felipe, welcome to askUbuntu! To format a line as code, you have to put 4 spaces in front of the command.

Answer (score -1):

I personally, didn't find any of these answers helpful - none of them placed wlan0 back into "station" mode, which is how it gets your internet connection back.

Let's start from the beginning:

You use airmon-ng start  (like, wlan0), and it gives the feedback:

"monitor mode vif enabled for  (wlan0mon)
station mode vif disabled for  "

Right, so then you do your airodump/aircrack/whatever -

But, then how you do get it back?

The "service  restart" commands didn't seem to work for me. What did was using "airmon-ng stop "

. . It gave some pretty sketchy feedback, though: 
" You are trying to stop a device that isn't in monitor mode. Doing so is a terrible idea, if you really want to do it then you need to type 'iw wlan0 del' yourself since it is a terrible idea. Most likely you want to remove an interface called wlan[0-9]mon. If you feel you have reached this warning in error, please report it."

Well, as a "last resort", it's not really a terrible idea, now is it? At this point, you've played around enough, such that rebooting didn't seem like the inconvenience you originally thought, right?

Go ahead and do the "iw  del" command. It'll remove your wireless device - Wlan0(mon), or whichever.

Check the results with iwconfig .

. . . Your device shouldn't appear.

Go back to airmon-ng start . It should say that it doesn't have a device by that name, and ask if you'd like to assign it. Say Yes.

This should re-create wlan0 and place it into default "station" mode, bringing back your connectivity.